# Error in SQL syntax in the php script

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql-server

I am trying to connect my android app to an online database, but an sql error pops out in the process

> Failed You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'qry' at line 1

this is the php script

```
<?php
$name = "localhost";
$username ="**********";
$password ="**********";
$servername ="*********";
$conn = mysqli_connect($name,$username,$password,$servername);
$typee=$POST["typee"];
$heighte=$POST["heighte"];
$weighte=$POST["weighte"];
$ranke=$POST["ranke"];
    $typee = $conn->real_escape_string($typee);
    $hieghte = $conn->real_escape_string($hieghte);
    $weighte = $conn->real_escape_string($weighte);
    $ranke = $conn->real_escape_string($ranke);
$qry = "INSERT INTO Naruto(typee,heighte,weighte,ranke)VALUES('$typee','$heighte','$weighte','$ranke')";
 if(mysqli_query($conn,qry)===TRUE)
           echo "Success";
       else
          echo "Failed ".$conn->error; 
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Don't mix mysqli_ object-oriented and mysqli_ procedural styles. `mysqli_query($conn,qry)` should be `$conn->query($qry)`. Change that and then report back. Edit: ha, also, you're missing a `$` before `qry`

Comment: Thanks. it worked!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the $conn to mysqli_query

For example,

```
 if(mysqli_query($conn,qry)===TRUE)
    echo "Success";
else
    echo "Failed ".$conn->error;
```

Additionally, you are not validating input or escaping which means if any of the values have a ' character it will break your query and the syntax will not longer be valid.

```
$typee=$mysqli->real_escape_string($POST["typee"]);
$heighte=$mysqli->real_escape_string($POST["heighte"]);
$weighte=$mysqli->real_escape_string($POST["weighte"]);
$ranke=$mysqli->real_escape_string($POST["ranke"]);
```

Additionally, hackers can perform an attack called sql injection to pass specially crafted strings to your database to compromise it or the system that is running it.

See this for more: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

In your particular example, also check that spacing is not an issue.

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO Naruto(typee,heighte,weighte,ranke) VALUES('$typee','$heighte','$weighte','$ranke')";
```

Also, In your updated post, you have misspelled variables so $heighte still isn't being escaped:

```
$heighte=$POST["heighte"];
...
$hieghte = $conn->real_escape_string($hieghte);
```

Comment: Sorry brother didn't work.Thanks for suggestions! I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: See additional edits, you have misspelled variables.

Answer (score 0):

Are all of your fields in the db of varchar type? Enclosing each type in the 
' ' might be causing problems when for example,heighte, is an integer.Check once.

Comment: Yes. i have checked they are.